# ¿Como restar dos vectores de gran tamaño?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas

Quiero calcular la diferencia vectorial entre dos vectores de gran dimensión.
Puedo restar una lista de matrices a una matriz y ponerlo a la potencia de 2

```
(train["quest_emb"][0] - train["sent_emb"][0])**2
```

pero no para generalizarlo con una columna de cuadro de datos de listas de matrices a un marco de datos de matrices:

```
train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"]
```

como congela mis computadoras

#### Análisis de matriz

Aquí hay un ejemplo de sus contenidos.

```
>>> print((train["quest_emb"][2]))
[[0.03949683 0.04509903 0.01808935 ... 0.04610749 0.0416535  0.02240689]]

>>> print((train["sent_emb"][2]))
[array([0.03037658, 0.04433101, 0.08135635, ..., 0.06764812, 0.04971079,
       0.02240689], dtype=float32), array([0.05260669, 0.04548098, 0.0382337 , ..., 0.04823414, 0.07656007,
       0.03501297], dtype=float32), array([0.0502927 , 0.04480611, 0.02038252, ..., 0.03942193, 0.03132772,
       0.04595207], dtype=float32), array([0.06769167, 0.03393815, 0.0625218 , ..., 0.05555448, 0.03059104,
       0.03422254], dtype=float32)]
```

Parece que hay una diferencia de tamaño:

```
>>> print(len(train["quest_emb"][0]))
1
>>> print(len(train["sent_emb"][0]))
4
```

Aquí es cómo se ve la primera matriz:

```
>>> print((train["quest_emb"][2][0]))
[0.03949683 0.04509903 0.01808935 ... 0.04610749 0.0416535  0.02240689]

>>> print((train["sent_emb"][2][0]))
[0.03037658 0.04433101 0.08135635 ... 0.06764812 0.04971079 0.02240689]
```

La longitud de `train [" quest_emb "]` es la misma con `train [" sent_emb "]`: 130318

Aquí están los tipos de matrices

```
>>> print(type(train["quest_emb"][2]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> print(type(train["sent_emb"][2]))
<class 'list'>
```

**¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esta diferencia computable para una computadora con 8G de RAM? O si no de una manera aproximada?**

#### Intento con theano

Bajo la guía de Roberto Pintos López intenté restarle a Theano:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
x = T.vector('x')
y = T.vector('y')
z = x - y
f = function([x, y], z)   
f(train["quest_emb"],train["sent_emb"])
```

pero me da:

```
@DaviMello 
ValueError: Bad input argument with name "quest_emb" to theano function with name "<ipython-input-28-47a895040788>:6" at index 0 (0-based).
```

Answer (score -1):

Éste parece un problema ideal para utilizar la tarjeta gráfica. La lentitud de las operaciones se debe a que todas tus operaciones son realizadas por un solo hilo, por un solo procesador lógico.

Puedes hacer una pequeña mejora utilizando varios hilos y, en el mejor de los casos, el tiempo se dividirá entre el número de procesadores lógicos de tu procesador (que a lo sumo, en ordenadores personales es de 32 https://www.xataka.com/componentes/intel-saca-24-cores-amd-saca-32-bienvenidos-al-threadripper-segunda-generacion). Sin embargo, esta optimización es mala en comparación con el uso de la tarjeta gráfica, pues una GPU normalilla puede tener alrededor de 1000 (sí, no es una errata) procesadores lógicos. Son mucho más restrictivos que los cores de los procesadores, pero están diseñados para hacer operaciones con vectores, como es tu caso.

Para python puedes probar la siguiente librería, http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/

Espero que sea de utilidad.

**Edición:**

Ejemplo de código funcionando correctamente:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, division
import theano
a = theano.tensor.dmatrix()  # declare variable
b = theano.tensor.dmatrix()  # declare variable
out = a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 2 * a * b  # build symbolic expression
f = theano.function([a, b], out)   # compile function
print(f([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]])) # prints [[-7. -1.]
                                             #         [ 9. 23.]]
```

Comment: Ok, no sé nada de Theano (es usar varios hilos, ¿eso es todo?) Y para usar mi tarjeta gráfica. Trataré de comenzar con Theano para hacer este cálculo y te dejaré saber.

Comment: Usar hilos (del procesador) es una solución, eso es, pero te recomiendo que le des una oportunidad a Theano para usar la tarjeta gráfica (que gestiona sus propios hilos). Esperaré los resultados, mucha suerte

Comment: De acuerdo, probé suerte ... sin éxito. Pero actualicé.

Comment: A ver si puedo echarle un ojo a lo largo de la semana y te paso un ejemplo.

Comment: Hola ThePassenger, estás usando el ejemplo de escalares cuando quieres operar con vectores, por favor consulta http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/adding.html#exercise

Comment: Como puedes ver si lees la documentación, T.dscalar es el tipo para escalares, el tipo que te interesa es T.vector.

Comment: Oh sí, de hecho. Lo siento. Actualicé pero siempre me da el mismo error.

Comment: Vale, me siento un poco estúpido jajaja, no me he dado cuenta de que train["quest_emb"] es una matriz, prueba pls con dmatrix. Este fin de semana lo intento en mi máquina si no te funciona

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con un ejemplo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81816/discussion-between-thepassenger-and-roberto-pintos-lopez).

Comment: Me tengo que ir a comer sry :(